# Chrome extension - Notification.requestPermission() does not ask for permission

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I created a chrome extension which also generate notifications using [Web API - Notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification).

The problem is when I invoke Notification.requestPermission() it does not ask for permission and notifications are not displayed.

**Observations:**

1. Chrome --> Settings --> Show Advanced options... --> Privacy --> Content Settings --> "Allow all sites..."
   The notifications are displayed.
2. Plain JavaScript works - Is it related somehow to the fact it runs inside a chrome extension?

How should I solve it?

Edit:
My code.

```
if (Notification.permission !== "granted") {
      Notification.requestPermission()
           .then(function() {});
};
```

When I debug the code Notification.permission === "default".

Comment: Did you add the "notifications" permission?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it by adding the "notifications" permissions in the manifest.json

Comment: Ugh I hate how there's no error to give me a hint. Is there?